WooCommerce Webhook Action When a New Product Review was Submitted/Created
I'm looking for a WooCommerce action hook, whenever someone submits a product review via the review/comment form. Can't find anything about this in the documentation or web.
I like to trigger a WooCommerce webhook, when that event fires, to run some other actions via external services.
So this should be something like i.e. action.woocommerce_order_status_completed, which I already use successfully.
So what I'm looking for is something like "action.woocommerce_review_created" … Any ideas?

As we know WooCommerce product reviews are essentially WordPress comments with a specific comment_type.
Firstly we hook into the Comment Submission and then we will check If the Comment is a WooCommerce Product Review and then we trigger our Custom Action.
Could you please try to add this to your theme’s functions.php or in your custom plugin.
function customized_woocommerce_review_comment_hook( $comment_id, $comment_approved ) {
    // Here we are checking if the comment is approved and if it's a WooCommerce product review.
    if ( $comment_approved && get_comment_type( $comment_id ) === 'review' ) {
        // You can add your custom action here
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_created', $comment_id );
        
        // Optionally, we can also add a webhook trigger here.
        // For example, here we are sending data to an external service.
        $comment    = get_comment( $comment_id );
        $product_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
        
        // Here we are preparing the data to send.
        $data = [
            'product_id'     => $product_id,
            'review_id'      => $comment_id,
            'review_content' => $comment->comment_content,
            'review_author'  => $comment->comment_author,
            // Add more fields as per the need.
        ];
        
        // Here we are sending the data to the webhook URL.
        $webhook_url = 'https://your-webhook-url.com'; //We need to replace this with our webhook URL.
        wp_remote_post($webhook_url, [
            'body'    => json_encode($data),
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'customized_woocommerce_review_comment_hook', 10, 2 );

Hope this will helps to you.

Works like a charm! Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!
